# 20.04.1 LTS Intel 8265 Wireless Non Functional. Bluetooth Works

Tags: networking

Fresh Install of **Ubuntu 20.04.1** with a functioning 8265 wireless card. Bluetooth works, but wifi is not recognized. `lspci` lists the card. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.
Also, this machine had it's `bios` recently hardware flashed to remove a `bios` password. This blew away the machine serial number and the windows product key but everything else is still functional and was functional in a Windows install.

Answer (score 1):

Solved. Several restarts later and the wifi is working.